# displaying b3 table for groups

Tags: php, mysql, b3

I'm working on a small, easy (to most of you I'm sure) project here.  In short, there is an admin 'tool' called B3 which stores data in mysql.  I have pieced together a small php to grab all levels of admin and display brief detail.  The tool is designed to easily check who has admin capabilities, and what level they are.  The couple extra details are admittedly fluff that probably won't remain (more of a proof of concept kind of thing for me.)

What I have works just fine and does as I outlined above.  However, I would like to take it one step further and make it more "user friendly".  There is a second table that contains the number level listed in group_bits, and assigns a user friendly name to it, eg 16 may be Moderator.

I know this is probably preschool level for most of you, but I've searched all over and just don't know what the proper phrasing for what I want to do is..

Essentially, while displaying my output, I want it to "I THINK" do a foreach on the group+bits and display the correct access level instead of just the group_bits id.  Ideally it would pull that info from teh groups table, where the number and name are identified, but I'd settle just as happily for it to be hardcoded, sort of an "if $group_bits=16 then $group="Moderator").  Whatever gets the job done, lol..  Universally would be better to get it from the table itself, right, so if it's changed, than this file wouldn't have to be altered, but I'm sensing that might be much more difficult?  Below are some helpful details, as well as what I have:

My php:

```
//We connect to a   database using the mysql_connect command.
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error()); 

//We select the database we are  going to use.
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 

//$query="SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY name DESC";
$query="SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE group_bits >'1'";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);  //Counts the rows in the table
echo "" .$screweditup ;
mysql_close();

?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Player Name</font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">B3 Level</font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Times Connected</font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Greeting Msg</font></td>
        <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font></td>
    </tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    for each($
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"group_bits");
    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"connections");
    $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"greeting");

    //$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"greeting");
?>

<tr>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
    <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
</tr>
```

clients is the table which holds the info you see being used.
groups holds the table where the group_bits and actual groups names are located..  It looks like this (table view:)

```
id               name                keyword
16               Admin               admin
8                Moderator           mod
0                Guest               guest
```

(the numeric in the groups table is called id, but is called group_bits in the clients table - They are one and the same, but under different names..
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

151

Comment: Anyone else?  The answer provided did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT g.name
              ,c.* FROM clients c 
                   JOIN groups g 
        WHERE group_bits >'1' 
          AND c.group_bits=g.group_bits";
```

Will put the groups.name column in front of all of your results.

I'm not exactly sure why you are backticking, you may have to add those again.

Comment: Didn't work for me at all, not with the "backticks" and not as you have it (even tried placing the ' before and/or different areas as I wasn't sure whether to include them with the "letter period" parts you added.

Comment: REVISED: Didn't work for me at all, not with the "backticks" and not as you have it (even tried ' before and/or areas as I wasn't sure whether to include them with the "letter period" parts you added.  As to why I used them not sure what to say.  The sample code I looked at used them.  I did remove them from my original php and it worked, so I'll leave them out.  I did/change the names for the f1-4 trying to use c.group_bits and g.group_bits and even g.name, but no matter what I put the end result was just the chart key line (name group bits connections greeting) from the php section above it.

Comment: please post the table structure